# How do you position a MDChip through code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Im working on a app and cant figure out how to position the MDChip. Basically i want to add a new MDChip on a MDCard. I want the MDChips to be positioned in the center and for every new one that is added then to go down. Here is my python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip
from kivy.lang import Builder

class App(MDApp):

    Current_Item = 0
    Chips = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        return self.screen

    def add_item(self):
        self.Chips.append(MDChip(text = self.root.ids.text_field_1.text, icon = "close-circle-outline", on_press = self.remove_item, pos_hint = {"center_x": 100, "center_y": 0.95}))
        self.root.ids.card_1.add_widget(self.Chips[self.Current_Item])
        self.Current_Item += 1
        self.root.ids.text_field_1.text = ""

    def remove_item(self, obj):
        self.Current_Item -= 1
        self.root.ids.card_1.remove_widget(self.Chips[self.Current_Item])
        self.Chips.pop()

App().run()
```

My kv file:

```
MDScreen:
    MDTextField:
        id: text_field_1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        
    MDIconButton:
        icon: "plus-circle"
        id: button_enter
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.82, "center_y": 0.95}
        on_press: app.add_item()

    MDCard:
        id: card_1 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        size_hint_y: 0.8
```

Comment: `MDCard` is a subclass of the class `BoxLayout`. Thus you can set its attribute `orientation` to 'vertical' to position its children vertically bottom to top. If you want to place them right in the middle, you may prefer `FloatLayout` or even `StackLayout`. However, shouldn't the `center_x` value of `MDChip`'s `pos_hint` be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ApuCoder I've found a valid answer by adding a StackLayout to MDCard.

```
MDCard:
        id: card_1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        size_hint_y: 0.8
        orientation: "vertical"

        StackLayout:
            id: stack_layout_1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.1
            spacing: 5
```

and this changing this line:

```
self.Chips.append(MDChip(text = self.root.ids.text_field_1.text, icon = "close-circle-outline", on_press = self.remove_item, pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5}))
```